# How to create a COM DLL (class library) in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, dll, com

How can I create a COM DLL (class library) in Delphi?

It is for use on very old PCs where .NET is not, and will not be, installed and will replace, and slightly extend, a VB 6 DLL for which I have the source code.

Comment: I know I keep banging on about this, but if you build it with Delphi then you may find it hard to have it consumed by a 64 bit process. This may not be an issue to you, and would certainly have been true for the VB6 version, but if you are looking to the future then it's worth being aware of.

Comment: +1 Thanks. Not sure if it's a problem or not; I will code it & see. Basically, a web site servers a page with some JS which calls into the COM DLL (great design, huh?)

Comment: JS can call into COM? Ouch! Presumably there are some limitations on the browsers that can be used and it has to be IE. In that case 32 bit is fine since nobody runs 64 bit IE.

Comment: David - 64 bit delphi will hopefully be released in XE2 which is the next release scheduled.

Comment: +1 (to both of you). Ouch indeed, but I have to live with it; it's live in the field & has been for 8 years or more. And, yes ... however did you know ... it's MSIE only (any version, no matter how old, afaik)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you have how to do it:

An Introduction to COM Programming with Delphi
So, what is an Interface?
An interface is the heart of COM technology. When I use the word interface, do not confuse it with the visual display that the user interacts with. It is actually a fairly new reserved word incorporated into Delphi. An Interface is little more than group of abstract methods used to manipulate an object.

We established during the last lesson that an interface is not a class; it is an interface. Therefore, we must declare it as such. Let us explore some interface characteristics.

- An interface is defined as type interface
- You are to use the letter I to define your interface. I.E. "IMyInterface = interface"
- An interface inherits from IUnknown
- You cannot create an instance of an interface like you can a class that contains abstract methods
- An interface cannot contain variables. (Read: It can contain properties as I will show you later on)
- All functions and procedures declared in an interface are public virtual abstract methods. Even though you do not declare them this way, it is understood that is what they are.
- Interfaces are reference counted

Now that we know more about what an interface can and cannot do, let us look at what it is like to declare an interface.

```
IMyInterface = interface
['{676C8DA0-D8B3-11D4-BDE0-00A024BAF736}']
procedure SomeUnimplementedMethod;
end;
```

On GUIDs
I am sure you are wondering what the big string of crazy characters are. It is called a GUID and it stands for Globally Unique Identifier. Some people pronounce it as "gwid" or as "Gooey I.D.". Here some characteristics of a GUID:

- Your interface will have a GUID unlike any other in the world
- All interfaces and COM interfaces will have a GUID attached to it
- You can create a GUID in Delphi by pressing CTRL-SHIFT-G
- You are never to copy a GUID from one interface into another

Okay, but how do I implement an interface?
That is a good question. The answer is: You cannot implement an interface directly. You must create a class that will implement your interface. Refer to the coding example shown below.

```
unit InterfaceUnit;

interface

uses
Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes,
Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
IMyInterface = interface
['{6675C5C0-D95C-11D4-BDE0-00A024BAF736}']
procedure DisplaySomething;
end;

TMyClass = class(TInterfacedObject, IMyInterface)
procedure DisplaySomething;
end;

TMyForm = class(TForm)
TestBtn: TButton;
procedure TestBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
end;

var
MyForm: TMyForm;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}
procedure TMyForm.TestBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
//Declare a TMyClass object
MyClass : TMyClass;
//Declare a IMyInterface Object
MyInterface : IMyInterface;
begin
//Create an interface pointing
//to a TMyClass object
MyInterface := TMyClass.Create;

//Call TMyClass'es DisplaySomething
//using our interface
MyInterface.DisplaySomething;
end;

{ TMyClass }
procedure TMyClass.DisplaySomething;
begin
ShowMessage('MyInterface was created and
will now fall out of scope!');
end;

end.
```

The coding example listed above is about as simple as it can get while still having some type of visual functionality. Let's take a closer look at procedure TextBtnClick. Is there something missing? If you haven?t notice, we are not explicitly freeing the interface. This would appear to be a memory leak, but appearances are deceiving. As soon as the interface goes out of scope, Delphi will actually free the interface for you automatically! Interface's declared within a procedure or function will naturally fall out of scope when the procedure ends. Interface's declared within a class or are declared globally will naturally fall out of scope when the object is freed or the program ends.

Now we need to discuss Reference Counting. Every time you retrieve an interface to an object, e.g. IMyInterface := MyClass; Delphi will automatically increment its reference count using IUnknown's _AddRef function. When an interface falls out of scope, Delphi automatically calls IUnknown's ._Release function. If you haven't figured it out yet, IUnkown is an interface as well, and since we already know that an interface cannot implement the methods it defines, then you may be wondering where AddRef and Release come from. The answer is TInterfacedObject!
What in the world is TInterfacedObject?
TInterfacedObject and IUnknown are defined in system.pas. Before I can elaborate on this, we need to at least take a look at the code:

SYSTEM.PAS
Declaration of IUnkown
Declaration of TInterfacedObject and its implementation

```
IUnknown = interface
['{00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}']
function QueryInterface
(const IID: TGUID; out Obj): HResult; stdcall;
function _AddRef: Integer; stdcall;
function _Release: Integer; stdcall;
end;

TInterfacedObject = class(TObject, IUnknown)
protected
FRefCount: Integer;
function QueryInterface
(const IID: TGUID; out Obj): HResult; stdcall;
function _AddRef: Integer; stdcall;
function _Release: Integer; stdcall;
public
procedure BeforeDestruction; override;
property RefCount: Integer read FRefCount;
end;

procedure TInterfacedObject.BeforeDestruction;
begin
if RefCount <> 0 then Error(reInvalidPtr);
end;

function TInterfacedObject.QueryInterface
(const IID: TGUID; out Obj): HResult;
const
E_NOINTERFACE = $80004002;
begin
if GetInterface(IID, Obj) then
Result := 0 else Result := E_NOINTERFACE;
end;

function TInterfacedObject._AddRef: Integer;
begin
Result := InterlockedIncrement(FRefCount);
end;

function TInterfacedObject._Release: Integer;
begin
Result := InterlockedDecrement(FRefCount);
if Result = 0 then Destroy;
end;
```

The code may look a little scary, but we are going to walk through this step-by-step since it is crucial that you understand reference counting in order to effectively program in COM. It is obvious from the code above that TInterfacedObject implements the methods defined in IUnkown. When you create a class that uses TInterfacedObject, you are essentially telling that class that it is going to be reference counted if an interface is assigned to it.

Let us look at simple piece of code so that I can describe the process that takes place.

```
TMyInterfaceClass = class(TInterfacedObject, IMyInterface)
{blah blah blah}
{blah blah blah}
procedure DoThis;
var
MyClass : TMyInterfaceClass;
MyInterface : IMyInterface;
begin
MyClass := TMyInterfaceClass.Create;
MyInterface := MyClass
end;
```

When you use Direct Assignment to assign MyInterface to MyClass, the method _AddRef gets called automatically by Delphi. This says to MyClass, "Hey, an interface is referencing you! Were going to increment your reference count." If you were to change the aforementioned code to the following:

```
TMyInterfaceClass = class(TInterfacedObject, IMyInterface)
{blah blah blah}
{blah blah blah}
procedure DoThis;
var
MyClass : TMyInterfaceClass;
MyInterface : IMyInterface;
MyInterface2: IMyInterface;
begin
MyClass := TMyInterfaceClass.Create;
MyInterface := MyClass;
MyInterface2 := MyClass
end;
```

Notice that I added a new variable called MyInterface2. Since we are now setting 2 different interfaces equal to MyClass, guess what happens to the Myclass?s reference count? It becomes 2 because we now have two interfaces assigned to it!

You may be wondering about the _Release method that is implemented by TInterfacedObject. The _Release method automatically gets called for each interface assigned to a class that falls out of scope. Obviously, at the end of procedure DoThis, the program execution is going to return whence it came, therefore, your local class and interface declarations fall out of the scope in which they were declared. Since we have two interfaces defined, _Release will get called how many times? The answer is a bright shiny "2"! And once our reference count hits zero, then MyClass is automatically freed by Delphi. How nice and clean!

[source of the answer](http://sinauonline.50webs.com/Artikel/Delphi%20Interface1.html)

Comment: Provided link is not available.

Comment: delphi.about.com seems to be dead. Added another resouce.

Answer (score 6):

You create a new ActiveX Library. You find it in the ActiveX tab. (File - New - Other - ActiveX - ActiveX Library)

Answer (score 3):

Go through [this site](http://www.techvanguards.com/) which is good start point to develop COM in Delphi. It is having tutorials, articles, and code on COM technologies in Delphi. It might be helpful to you